# How do i delete an element of a json object with python?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to delete elements from _notes that have _type as 1, but i keep getting an error and I'm not sure what it means, nor do I know how to fix it.. can anyone help me?

My trimmed JSON:

```json
{
    "_notes": [
        {
            "_time": 10,
            "_lineIndex": 2,
            "_lineLayer": 0,
            "_type": 0,
            "_cutDirection": 7
        },
        {
            "_time": 12,
            "_lineIndex": 2,
            "_lineLayer": 0,
            "_type": 1,
            "_cutDirection": 1
        },
        {
            "_time": 14,
            "_lineIndex": 2,
            "_lineLayer": 1,
            "_type": 1,
            "_cutDirection": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

My python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json
obj = json.load(open("ExpertPlusStandardd.dat"))

for i in range(len(obj["_notes"])):
    print(obj["_notes"][i]["_type"])
    if obj["_notes"][i]["_type"] == 1:
        obj.pop(obj["_notes"][i])

open("test.dat", "w").write(
    json.dumps(obj, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
)
```

Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\programming\python\train_one_hand\run.py", line 9, in <module> obj.pop(obj["_notes"][i]) TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: as for me this JSON data can't give your error message - you have to check what you really have in your file `"ExpertPlusStandardd.dat"`

Comment: edited the error message

Comment: i copied the contents of ExpertPlusStandardd.dat into my question

Comment: it is wrong idea to remove (`pop`) item from object which you use in `for`-loop - because it moves items on list and later it tries to use index which doesn't exists any more. You should rather create new JSON and put in this JSON elements which you want to keep

Comment: I found two problems - (1) you run `pop` on wrong object - it has to be `obj["_notes"].pop` instead of `obj.pop`, (2) `pop` needs `index` instead of `item` - `obj["_notes"].pop(i)`. But this makes problem which I mentioned before - after removing one item other items are moved to new indexes and later `i` is too big and it gives error `IndexError: list index out of range` - so you should filter which element to keep instead of remove item which you don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a bad idea to delete from a list that you're iterating. Reverse iterating avoids some of the pitfalls, but it is much more difficult to follow code that does that, so usually you're better off using a list comprehension or filter.

```
obj["_notes"] = [x for x in obj["_notes"] if x["_type"] != 1]
```

This gives us the expected output :

```
{'_notes': 
   [
       {
            '_time': 10, 
            '_lineIndex': 2, 
            '_lineLayer': 0, 
            '_type': 0, 
            '_cutDirection': 7
       }
   ]
}
```